# Parsing data scraped from Javascript rendered webpage with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to use .find off of a soup variable but when I go to the webpage and try to find the right class it returns none.

```html
from bs4 import *
import time
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import html5lib
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
url = "https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply"


def get_data(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    global soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def get_next_page(soup):
    page = soup.find('div', {'class': 'dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers'})
    return page
    
get_data(url)
print(get_next_page(soup))
```

The "page" variable returns "None" even though I pulled it from the website element inspector. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the website is rendered with javascript but can't figure out why. If I take away the {'class' : ''datatables_paginate paging_simple_numbers'} and just try to find 'div' then it works and returns the first div tag so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: modern pages may use JavaScript to add elements and BS can't run JavaScript. You may need `selenium` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. You can turn off JavaScript in browser and reload page to see if page uses JavaScript.

Comment: this page may have all data inside HTML but in `<script>` as `cl.coinmainlist.dataraw = [ ...]` but they would need some tool to convert it to something useful - and this can be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

So you want to **scrape** dynamic page content , You can use beautiful soup with selenium webdriver. This answer is based on explanation here *https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrape-content-from-dynamic-websites/*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://cryptoli.st/lists/fixed-supply"
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver') 
driver.get(url) 
  
# this is just to ensure that the page is loaded
time.sleep(5) 
  
html = driver.page_source
  
# this renders the JS code and stores all
# of the information in static HTML code.
  
# Now, we could simply apply bs4 to html variable
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```